# Is performance affected by using namespaces in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, namespaces, xna

I'm creating a game in XNA 4.0 and C#. Whenever I create a new class, it always generates the following four lines of code at the top.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

In most cases, these namespaces are not necessary to use in my classes as I do not need to explicitly call the methods that they provide. Should I remove them from each class where they are not being used? Is there an impact on performance if I leave these lines of code in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are "consumed" by the compiler, and aren't present in the compiled code. So the compiled code is unaffected by the number of the `using` statesment present. Clearly the compiler will be slown a little if there are too many `using`s (but only a little).

You can see it from here: http://goo.gl/T5TIYx On the right pane there is the IL code that is "generated" by the compiler. There is no trace of the various `using`s.

The compiler will be slowed a little if you have too many `using` because when you reference a type, it has to check for each namespace if there is the type you are referencing, and it can't stop at the first "success", because the C# compiler tells you even if there is some ambiguity (class with same name in two different namespaces)